# Unable to change widget inside StackedWidget

Tags: python, qt, widget, pyqt

I am trying to replace a widget for another. I am using a StackedWidget. I have the following.

First, I register add some widgets to the StackedWidget:

```
    self.stackedWidget.addWidget(w1)
    self.stackedWidget.addWidget(w2)
    self.stackedWidget.addWidget(w3)
```

The I bind the click of a button of w1:

```
    QObject.connect(w1.pushButton,SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.stackedWidget,SLOT(self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(w2)))
```

For Slot I have also tried "setCurrentIndex". I checked if the signal is being received, and it is ok.

Finally, I show w1.

```
self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(w1)
```

Although the "clicked()" signal is received when the button of w1 is pressed, the widget w2 never appears in the StackedWidget.

UPDATE:

I am doing

```
    QObject.connect(w1.pushButton,SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.stackedWidget,SLOT('w1Clicked()'))
```

as suggested; however, I get

```
Object::connect: No such slot QStackedWidget::w1Clicked()
Object::connect:  (sender name:   'pushButton')
Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'stackedWidget')
```

I guess I have to create the slot "w1Clicked" somehow, but I am using the designer I can't figure it out.

I have one Main Window with the StackedWidget and separate forms with the buttons, so I don't see how to make the connection or create slots.

Also, I discovered that the problem with the way I was doing:

```
    QObject.connect(w1.pushButton,SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.stackedWidget,SLOT(self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(w2)))
```

is that "self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(w2)" gets executed immediately, it does not wait for the signal! That's why w2 was never shown.

Still I have no idea.

Comment: Your post seems to be missing something...

Comment: Could it be that you have two w2 widgets added?

Comment: I only add three widgets: w1,w2,w3. Once each one. If I show w2 instead of w1 at the beginning, it is fine, but the same way, I cannot show w1 or w3 after the event.

Comment: Check the code you added. There is no w3...

Comment: Fixed. Too many hours in front of the pc *_*

Answer (score 2):

Your `connect` call is wrong.  You can't define what values are going to be passed to your slot when you make the connection. Instead you need to create your own slot and handle the signal as you desire (apologies if my python syntax is off):

```
QObject.connect(w1.pushButton,SIGNAL("clicked()"),self,SLOT("w1Clicked()"))

def w1Clicked(self):
    self.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(w2)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have read that a in C slot must be created as public, but I don't know how to do it in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it worked this way:

```
w1.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.w1Clicked)
```

At least the signal is received and the method is called correctly.